# Create OS user specific Drush commands

Tags: drush

I know how to create `drush` commands in a *project*, but there are a number of commands which I would like to add *to my local system* simply because they affect my particular workflow a lot.

In Clisp, I can define this in `.clisprc.lisp`. In `git` I can add commands to the `~/.gitconfig` command, I'm looking for similar for Drush.

So, for example, I might like to have a locally defined Drush command, `add-squeeky-table`:

```
drush add-squeeky-table
```

And I would be able to call that on all Drupal 7 projects installed on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your extensions in ~/.drush.

If add-squeeky-table is a drush command, put it in ~/.drush/squeekytable.drush.inc.  See [drushify](https://www.drupal.org/project/drushify).

If you want to define add-squeeky-table as a shell alias, put it in ~/.drush/drushrc.php.  See the [example Drush configuration file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drush-ops/drush/master/examples/example.drushrc.php).